# Heteroscedasticity,Autocorrelation,Chow test

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

Can a Chow test be run on a dataset which has autocorrelation and/or heteroscedasticity? Will the F-stat give accurate results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided an appropriate robust version of the statistic is used.

The Chow test is a special case of a general Wald test testing multiple restrictions, whose test statistic (in the $\chi^2$ version, which unlike the $F$ statistic version is justified, asymptotically, without error normality) is given by
$$
W=n(Rb-r)'\left[R\widehat{\mathrm{Avar}}(b)R'\right]^{-1}(Rb-r).
$$
Here, $R\beta=r$ is the null we test (coefficient equality of two subvectors in the case of the Chow test), and $b$ is the OLSE. Now, the test statistic will be asymptotically robust to heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation if you use a robust (aka Eicker-White) estimate $\widehat{\mathrm{Avar}}(b)$ of the asymptotic variance of the OLS estimator.

Comment: Actually I'm a bit of a novice, I'm just running 3 regressions,one each pre and post the structural break point, and one for the whole period. I am then calculating the F-stat. So will this approach work in the presence of heteroscedasticity/autocorreation?

Comment: It is not fully transparent how exactly you compute the test statistic, but my guess is no, as you do not seem to use robust asymptotic variance estimators