# Alternative to Chow test where the errors are not normally distributed

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, chow-test

I have timeseries data and want to identify if the change in coefficient at a particular point is significant.

One method to test for structural change is the Chow test which assumes i.i.d. errors drawn from a normal distribution.

However, the residual plot for my data shows the variance is non-constant and a normality test on the residuals fails (statistic $12.45$, $p=0.002$).

[image: residual plot with decreasing variance]

Is there another method I can use to determine if the change around a point is significant without assuming a constant/normal error distribution?

Comment: As can be seen in the plot, the test does not indicate non-normality. Rather, it indicates non-constant variance. So fit an appropriate heteroscedastic model, then test for structural change in the context of that model.

Comment: Yes the residuals indicate non-constant variance, but the test (`scipy.stats.normaltest` based on D'Agostino and Pearson's tests) is for normality and fails.

Could you elaborate on your suggestion to fit a heteroscedastic model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the normality test fails is because the residuals are heteroscedastic. Since the residuals are pooled across all X values, this makes their distribution a mixture of their conditional distributions. And even if all the conditional distributions are normal, their mixture will be non-normal. But the assumption is not that the errors are marginally normally distributed, it is instead that their conditional distributions are all normal.

But a perhaps bigger problem is that there appear to be structure in the residual plot that possibly indicates autocorrelation. This might be even worse than heteroscedasticity for the test.

In the case of either heteroscedasticity or autocorrelation, there are two main options: (1) fit a parametric model that addresses both violations, and perform the test using full-model, restricted-model likelihood ratio test, or (2) fit the ordinary OLS but use a robust estimate of the covariance matrix (one that allows both violations); see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/209524/102879.  There are pros and cons to each approach; see Chapter 12, "Heteroscedasticity and Non-independence" of the book [*Understanding Regression Analysis: A Conditional Distribution Approach.*](https://www.routledge.com/Understanding-Regression-Analysis-A-Conditional-Distribution-Approach/Westfall-Arias/p/book/9780367493516?utm_source=cjaffiliates&utm_medium=affiliates&cjevent=765c13cd606b11ed80cf62610a1c0e11)